# Proving that compositions of linear operators are equal.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be linear operators on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $B = \{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Suppose that each vector in $$ is an eigenvector of both $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Prove that $T_1 \circ  T_2 = T_2 \circ T_1$.

What I have tried:

Let $v$ be an arbitrary vector from $B$.

Then,

$T_1(v) = λ_1\cdot v$

$T_2(v) = λ_2\cdot v$

Hence,

$$T_1 \circ T_2 = T_1(T_2(v)) = T_1(λ_2\cdot v) = λ_1\cdot λ_2 \cdot(v)$$

$$T_2 \circ T_1 = T_2(T_1(v)) = T_2(λ_1\cdot v) = λ_2\cdot λ_1\cdot (v)$$

Hence, equal.

Is it sufficient proof?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No. You need to include the extra step that it holds for every $v\in \Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Your idea is correct but the proof requires a bit more. To prove that both maps are same, one should show that they agree on *all vectors* in the space $V$. What you have shown is that these two maps agree on a basis $B$, which will suffice provided you know and are able to use the fact that if two maps agree on a basis, then they will agree on the entire space.

Comment: Ted and Anurag, $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is arbitrary, so it holds for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The "problem" is not that. The "problem" is, you took a basis but didn't use, the basis vectors are the eigen vectors. So you need to open $v$ as a linear combination of $B$, then do the calculations you did.

Comment: @LeandroAbib That confused me as well (and I was about to post the comment that you did), but note that OP actually defines $v$ as an arbitrary vector in the basis $B$.

Comment: Yes, that was my idea here, since v is an arbitrary vector, does not it imply that it holds for any vector?

Comment: Alex, it does hold, but just like I have said, you can't assume any vector of $\mathbb{R}$ is an eigenvector for both operators. You need to open the linear combination of the vectors of $B$ and then continue the calculation you did. Other than that, it seems correct to me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I have edited your post to use the MathJax markup language we use here.  For a guide in doing so yourself in the future,  try https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. To see the code yourself in this post, just click edit and you can see it

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is almost correct, but not quite. To figure out why, you should figure out what each step of your argument means beyond the equation (maybe it helps to explain in words), and then you can see the gaps in your reasoning. Let me rephrase your argument:

> Let $v$ be an arbitrary vector in the basis $B$. Then there exist real numbers $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ such that $T_1(v)=\lambda_1 v$ and $T_2(v)=\lambda_2 v$ by hypothesis that all vectors of $B$ are eigenvectors of $T_1$ and $T_2$. Thus, $T_1T_2(v)=T_2T_1(v)$.

But note that this only proves $T_1T_2=T_2T_1$ for all vectors $v$ **in the basis** $B$, but not for any of the vectors outside the basis! This is because of how you defined $v$ as a vector of the basis $B$, not an arbitrary vector of $\mathbb R^n$. If you forget how you defined your notation, they will come back to bite you, especially since $v$ is normally used to denote a general vector and it is better notation to write $v_i$ for a particular basis vector.

Note that your argument does not immediately work if you just replace "arbitrary vector in the basis $B$" by "arbitrary vector in $\mathbb R^n$". This is because you do not know $T_1(v)=\lambda_1 v$ a priori for arbitrary vectors $v$, since you are only given that vectors of $B$ are eigenvectors of $T_1,T_2$ and not for all vectors of $\mathbb R^n$.

---

You have shown that $T_1T_2$ and $T_2T_1$ are the same on the basis $B$. The last step: prove that if two linear operators are the same on a basis, then they are the same on the whole vector space. Can you do this?

Comment: Thank you! I will try to figure it out.

Comment: But it does work for all vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$. They are all a linear combination of vectors of the basis and the operators are also linear. Thus, for all vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ the property holds.

Comment: @LeandroAbib yes, of course. I'm just pointing out that it wasn't proven in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You took an arbitrary $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. You can write it as
$$
v = \alpha_1 v_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n v_n,
$$
for some $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$. That's the part that was missing on your proof, because the basis $B = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ has the eigenvectors of both operators. Also, for more generality, assume that
$$
T_1 v_i = \lambda_i v_i
$$
and the same for $T_2$, but with $\lambda'_i$, for all $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$.